# Languages Or Dialects Not Distinguishing Between Taste And Smell

Tags: list-of-languages, vocabulary, anthropology

Are there any languages or dialects not distinguishing between *taste* and *smell*?

<sub>*Possible duplicate of [this](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/25598) older and much more general question.*</sub>

Comment: English for one subsumes smell under taste, insofar taste is mostly perceived by the nose, except for the four or five basic tastes sour, salt, sweet, bitter (and umami/meat), as the common knowledge goes.

Comment: @vectory: Languages or dialects having only one word for both these senses.

Comment: Mandarin uses the same word for smelling and hearing (闻 _wén_, although there’s also 听 _tīng_ used only for hearing or listening), which isn’t quite the same but seems somehow related.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: [Etymological explanation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/聞#Chinese).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Interesting! The same happens in the Slavic languages: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/слышать where, in Russian, _slyshat'_ is for _hearing_ and, colloquially, for _smelling, feeling a smell_ (more literary is _chujat'_), and very opposite case in Slovene, where _čúti_ (cognate for _chujat'_) & _slíšati_ are both for _hearing_.

Answer (score 2):

The OHG form of the modern German *schmecken* "taste" could mean [both "taste" and "smell"](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=DWB&bookref=5,2376,45#1).  This is, as the Grimms note, still preserved in Upper German dialects; I have myself heard it being used for "smell" in Lungau, a southern part of Salzburg, where the dialect is somewhat in the middle between South and Middle Bavarian.

Comment: The anecdote is acually quite funny. I, non-dialect L1 Austrian German speaker, was talking to a farmer in Lungau about silo hay, and he told me "schmecks amal", whereupon I _tasted_ a piece of hay, and he was rather perplexed about my reaction.

Comment: As a non-dialect L2 standard German speaker, I now feel silly. :-)